# how to define home path in htaccess to a certain html file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress shop powered by woocommerce. sometimes I run TV ads and during those commercials my server has to respond to huge number of requests. I also noticed that most of the visitors just visit my home page and don't go any deeper. so I created a light html-css page for my shop front page. is there any way to direct htaccess that if any request to my site like example.com, (without any subdomain, subdirectory or even query strings) came, send that html file without user noticing any change in url?

Currently I'm using a subdomain and put the html file in it's root:

```
Redirect / http://landing.example.com
```

but this lead to inconsistency to ajax requests (like when user is searching for products) and many plugins that I'm using.

Comment: Would probably make more sense to just put your static document under `index.htm`, and make sure the system looks for `index.htm` before `index.php` when trying to find a directory index file.